# Multi-level list of rasters - performing algebra in R

Tags: r, list, stack, lapply, raster

I have a multi level list of rasters and it always gives me a headache how to operate on such structures efficiently. I want to take averages from the rasters in 3rd level of the list, going by the indexes. For example:

```
# make some dummy rasters
a <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
a[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
b <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
b[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
c <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
c[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
d <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
d[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
e <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
e[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
f <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
f[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
g <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
g[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
h <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
h[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
i <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
i[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
j <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
j[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
k <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
k[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)
l <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
l[] <- sample(1:5,25,replace=T)

)

list_abcd <- list(a,b,c,d)
list_efgh <- list(e,f,g,h)
list_ijkl <- list(i,j,k,l)

list_all <- list(list_abcd,list_efgh,list_ijkl)
```

I want to perform calculations on the rasters to obtain the averages of the respective 1st rasters in the lists (average of `a,e and i`),
2nd (`b,f and j`), 3rd (`c,g,k`) and 4th (`d, h and l`).

The result will be a list containing 4 rasters.

In reality, I have a list structured like this for 10 groups, each with over 100 rasters, so the solution needs to be scalable.

---

**Additional info** I work with NetCDF files and their structure looks following (below). I create multi-level lists to handle it, but then have a headache how to handle it well without too many laborious `for` loops.

```
3 variables:
    double var1[lon,lat,years,irr]
    double var2[lon,lat,years,irr]
    double var3[lon,lat,years,irr]
 4 dimensions:
    lon  Size:720
        units: degrees_east
        long_name: lon
    lat  Size:360
        units: degrees_north
        long_name: lat
    years  Size:100
        units: mapping
        long_name: years
    irr  Size:2
        units: mapping
        long_name: rainfed/irrigated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=5,ymn=0,ymx=5,res=1)
set.seed(123)
list_abcd <- replicate(4, setValues(r, sample(1:5,25,replace=T)))
list_efgh <- replicate(4, setValues(r, sample(1:5,25,replace=T)))
list_ijkl <- replicate(4, setValues(r, sample(1:5,25,replace=T)))   
list_all <- list(list_abcd,list_efgh,list_ijkl)
names(list_all) <- c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl")
```

Solution, create a single `RasterStack` and use `stackApply`

```
x <- stack(unlist(list_all))
i <- rep(1:4, 3)
s <- stackApply(x, i, mean)
s
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 5, 5, 25, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 5, 0, 5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      :  index_1,  index_2,  index_3,  index_4 
#min values : 1.333333, 2.000000, 1.000000, 1.666667 
#max values : 4.666667, 5.000000, 4.666667, 4.333333
```

Now let's do this with `terra` (the replacement of `raster`). We start with three `SpatRaster`s (similar to a RasterStack)

```
library(terra)
rr <- rast(xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5,res=1)
set.seed(123)
abcd <- replicate(4, setValues(rr, sample(1:5,25,replace=T))) |> rast()
efgh <- replicate(4, setValues(rr, sample(1:5,25,replace=T))) |> rast()
ijkl <- replicate(4, setValues(rr, sample(1:5,25,replace=T))) |> rast()
# the above is equivalent to: abcd <- c(a,b,c,d)
```

Solution 1: Combine into a single `SpatRaster` and use `tapp`

```
rall <- c(abcd, efgh, ijkl) 
z1 <- tapp(rall, rep(1:4, 3), "mean")
```

Solution 2: Combine into a SpatRasterDataset and use `app`

```
rsd <- sds(abcd, efgh, ijkl) 
z2 <- app(rsd, "mean")
```

Solution 3: Use `mean` directly

```
z3 <- mean(abcd, efgh, ijkl)
```

---

**Later**: from your comment I gather the mistake you make is indeed in creating these lists. If I understand you well you have *n* files representing models, each with 2*100 layers; and you want to average the values of each layer (year & water status) across models; so that you end up with a single raster dataset of 200 layers (or 2 datasets with 100 layers). You can achieve that with something like this:

```
 library(terra)
 ff <- list.files(pattern="nc$")  
 sd <- sds(ff)
 x <- app(sd, mean)
```

Or, if irrigated/rainfed are separate sub-datasets, something like

```
 library(terra)
 ff <- list.files(pattern="nc$")  
 sd <- lapply(ff, \(i) rast(i, "irrigated")) |> sds()
 # or sd <- lapply(ff, \(i) rast(i, 1)) |> sds()
 x <- app(sd, mean)
```

With some example data

```
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
sd <- sds(c(f,f,f))
x <- app(sd, mean)
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem looks following. I have 10 model outputs in NetCDF format. Each contains arrays with dimensions of 360x720 corresponding to 0.5deg spatial resolution, 1:100 - number of years, and 1:2 - irrigation vs rainfed model outputs. I need a multi-model mean for each year, for rainfed and irrigated scenario. I have list of models and I am not sure how t structure data for most efficient calculations - I have all in lists format. I wonder if there is an example somewhere how to operate on such large data efficiently.

Comment: That is different question really, but I have tried to add an answer to that above.

Comment: Thank you for outlining such a nice solution, but it doesn't solve the problem - it returns 3 rasters instead of 4. The end product should be the length of the `abcd` raster. so the averages should iterate by the indexes of the 3rd level rasters - hope that is clear.

Comment: Since you have helped so much, I hope you don't mind this final addition about the structure of NetCDF. this will help me in long-term solutions. Terra looks amazing
`3 variables:`
`var1[lon,lat,years,irr], var2[lon,lat,years,irr], var3[lon,lat,years,irr]`
     `4 dimensions:`  `lon  Size:720, units: degrees_east, long_name: lon`  `lat  Size:360, units: degrees_north, long_name: lat`   `years  Size:100, long_name: years`  `irr  Size:2, long_name: rainfed/irrigated`

Comment: I think the first part now returns what you are after; the later addition already as OK. Beyond what I have shown for a generic case I cannot comment on your specific file. Especially not from this comment. You could show `rast(filename)` or `sds(filenames)` in you question --- but it would be better to ask a new question; and make the file(s) available if possible.